# Check if empty/null column exists in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, model, eloquent

I want to check if a row of my Compagny table contains empty or null column, in order to display a message to invite the user to fill his compagny's profile.

Is there a clean and fast way to do that in laravel controller ? Or do I have to do

```
if(empty($compagny->columnName) || empty($compagny->columnName))
    //content displaying view and message here
```

And do this for each column in my table ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

You can see that Eloquent returns a collection object - an object always passes an empty() check as True. Instead, do

```
if ( ! $compagny->isEmpty() )

Or even

if ( $compagny->count() )
```

Comment: Hmm i got a pb with this, i think it's because i do not get a collection object because i don't request a multi-result sets no ?

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: When i go on the compagny page : mywebsite.com/compagny/slug, i get the informations of the compagny, and i just want in my controller to check if this compagny has empty values in the table, for example if the description column is empty, and i want to know if there is a clean and fast way to do it

Comment: Yeah, this answer is good when you want to check an entire collection or row... but how do you check whether a specific column is null or not?